# Mousewheel scrolling on Infinite Scrolling EXTJS Grid isn't working

Tags: extjs, extjs4

we're using EXTJS 4.0.5 and having some issues with mousewheel scrolling.

We've got a bunch of infinite scrolling grids that require the setting:

`verticalScrollerType: 'paginggridscroller'`

So we put this setting on a base class and had all grids inherit from this class. They all scroll fine and the infinite pagination works while you scroll, but the mouse wheel behaviour is off.

Disabling this setting fixes mousewheel scrolling on the grids but obviously breaks the infinite scrolling pagination of the grid.

The behaviour I'm seeing is the mousewheel will not scroll while the cursor is over the records in the grid, but will scroll if the cursor is over the scrollbar.

Has anybody seen this issue before? I've found nothing in the documentation regarding mousewheel scrolling. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this was fixed in ExtJS 4.0.7 ? see the release notes @ http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/release-notes.html

I recommend you upgrade to 4.0.7 or 4.1.2 if you can. A lot of bugs were fixed in these releases.

Comment: Wish I could but people that were in this project before me have modified 4.0.5 and we don't have time to properly upgrade, thanks for the link though - I'll check it out!

Comment: Upgrading is definitely the proper solution here, as there are dozens of fixes for scrollers and the various grid issues we're having.